# How to identify fields with filters applied

Tags: excel, vba

I thought this question would be relatively easy but I can't find anything...

I've got a relatively large register of equipment with 1300+ rows and nearly 100 columns in Excel 2016. I can tell when a filter is applied because the visible rows have blue text.

Without manually looking across all of the header rows of a table how can I identify which fields have filters applied and select that column?

Even if it was as simple as a built-in function to Excel like 'Find Special...' that would be great.

TIA
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OzGrid has a similar question and some code by Stephen Bullen

https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/57953-determine-which-columns-are-filtered

```
Function FilterCriteria(Rng As Range) As String
    'By Stephen Bullen 
    Dim Filter As String
    Filter = ""
    On Error GoTo Finish
    With Rng.Parent.AutoFilter
        If Intersect(Rng, .Range) Is Nothing Then GoTo Finish
        With .Filters(Rng.Column - .Range.Column + 1)
            If Not .On Then GoTo Finish
            Filter = .Criteria1
            Select Case .Operator
                Case xlAnd
                    Filter = Filter & " AND " & .Criteria2
                Case xlOr
                    Filter = Filter & " OR " & .Criteria2
            End Select
        End With
    End With
Finish:
    FilterCriteria = Filter
End Function
```

Comment: I didn't get this to work specifically as I'd liked but I did adapt it for something else.